# How to remove key value from the table in loop in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

So, I created a table `A_table` and my goal is to create a set of three hands `Hand` and then I wanted to remove the last two sets from the table i.e `key 2 and 3`

```
A_table = {}

for i = 1, 3 do
  local  Hand = {
            ['parts'] = {
                type = 'arm',
                left = 'up',
                right = 'down',
                collision = 'true'
            }
        }
    
    table.insert(A_table, Hand)
end

for k, v in pairs(A_table) do
    print(k, v['parts'].left)
end
```

Output: -- Wanted to remove 2 and 3

```
1       up
2       up
3       up
```

I tried the following method but it didn't work.

```
for k, v in pairs(A_table) do
    for i = #v, 2, -1 do
        A_table[i] = nil
    end
end
```

Comment: Just omit the outer loop `for k, v in pairs(A_table) do` and it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case...

```
for i = #A_table, 2, -1 do
    table.remove(A_table)
end
```

1. The loop starts at last key and leaves after key number 2
2. table.remove() without positional parameter removes last key/value by default

Comment: Side note: `A_table[i] = nil` is just as valid and presumably more performant

Comment: @Jexter using ```table.insert()``` and not ```A_table[i] = Hand``` - So i thought i demonstrate how to use ```table.remove()```.